# How to analyse the range of eigenvalues of a symmetric and indefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

Let $G$ be a symmetric and indefinite matrix defined as follows

$$ G := S - \begin{pmatrix} I_n & I_n \\ I_n & I_n \end{pmatrix},$$

where $S$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix of size $2n\times 2n$. Numerical result shows that $G$ is an indefinite matrix and its range of eigenvalues is $(a,b)\cup(c,d)$, where $a<b<0<c<d$.

I want to estimate the bounds $a,b,c,d$, but I have no idea now. I read some literatures and gain nearly nothing. Could anyone provide me any ideas or literatures about the estimate of eigenvalues of a symmetric and indefinite matrix?

Comment: The first thing to try would probably be the [circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem). Depending on the circumstance it can be really useful but sometimes it's not very informative without transforming the matrix somehow.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo In fact, $S$ is a full matrix because $S$ is Schur complement of a sparse matrix $A$, and $A$ comes from the discretization of a second order elliptic equation.  Sorry, I omit some information but I didn't expect to cause so much confusion.